# PHP preg_match_all with Regular Expression applied to IMDB actor page

Tags: php, regex, expression

Hard question (for me at least) hope someone is able to help me as I already got lots of help here before! I have this code to get an actor image from the iMDB site

```
$string = FetchPage($url);
$image_regex_src_url = '/<td id="img_primary"[^>]*'. 'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
$img_tag_array = $out[0];
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$images_url_array = $out[1];
```

Take Kevin Costner as example here: http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000126/

I'm trying to adapt my code to fetch into a variable the integer of oscars won so far from this line: "Won 2 Oscars." and to another variable his birth date from the lines "Born:Kevin Michael Costner
January 18, 1955 in Lynwood, California, USA"

To end with something like this:

```
$actor_oscars = 2;
$actor_birthdate = "January 18, 1955";
```

The thing is, my knowledge of Regular Expressions is very very limited and I already tried to make this alone (on a trial and error basis) and failed completely! Any good soul out there to help me?

PS: I tried to put the code here on stackoverflow to look pretty but even with that I seem not to succeed at all!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's better to use a proper parser for this (don't parse HTML with regex). At least for that image. ;-)

Comment: Use DOM for this, it's much better. http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: I always suspected there would be a better method to achieve what I'm doing and wanting to do, but as I said my knowledge is limited and I can only work with the methods I understand. For this time, because I'm just wanting to fetch data just this one time and because (of course) I already have some code to work start with I'll have to stick with this method. :|

Comment: Got my answer! Thanks guys for the suggestions. I'll surelly look into it when I have some spare time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After each preg_match line $matches[1] will contain the desired result

Image URL:

```
preg_match( '/<td[^>]*id="img_primary".+?<img[^>]*src="([^"]+)"/s', $str, $matches );
```

Oscars Won:

```
preg_match( '/Won\s(\d+)\sOscars\./', $str, $matches );
```

Birth Month-Day:

```
preg_match( '/<a href="[^"]*birth_monthday[^"]*">(.+?)<\/a>/', $str, $matches );
```

Birth Year:

```
preg_match( '/<a href="[^"]+birth_year[^"]+">(.+?)<\/a>/', $str, $matches );
```

Comment: FANTASTIC! I officially declare you my go-to guy when in need of a php expert! :) Thanks for the effort and fpr the time you took to help me!

Comment: Just one more thing Autumn ... your code only works when an actor has won multiple oscars. Do you know what do I have to do if an actor just won 1 oscar (it says on the page "Won Oscar")? If he hasnt' one anything is easy ... I just have to see if the varible is defined and if it's not set it to 0 :)

Comment: `if( preg_match( '/Won\sOscar/', $str ) ) {
    $oscars = 1;
} elseif( preg_match( '/Won\s(\d+)\sOscars\./', $str, $matches ) ) {
    $oscars = $matches[1];
} else {
    $oscars = 0;
}`

Comment: And then again! Thanks Autumn! By the way ... you have an extra ; and a missing { in your code! Cheers mate! :)